# Construction of a user data and a function to associate them by an apply function

Tags: clojure, parameter-passing, apply

I am practicing a tutorial
[Clojure Design Patterns - Observer](http://mishadoff.com/blog/clojure-design-patterns/#episode-10-observer)

In the topic of Observer there is no approach of the user and applied function construction. When I tried to resolve them I was getting errors.

The problem is that the apply function converts an object to a seq. Another problem is that the apply function gets the object as multiple parameters, when it has multiple fields. Any ideas?

My code that does not work is this

```
(ns observer.core)

(defrecord person [name balance])
(def user (person. "alan" 434))
(apply
 (fn [& u]
   (println u)
   (println (str (:name u) " and  " (:balance u))))
   user)
(println "The end")
```

Output

```
([:name alan] [:balance 434])
 and  
The end
observer.core>
```

#### Update

My question is about what kind of programmatic structure should we use for the user data to implement the solution shown in the linked article. I put another question at Stackoverflow about the article but I asked there about just a map. In this question I actually mention several data structures or types that one can suggest. I do not determine the map.

Comment: The article you linked to is full of errors, or at least the section you linked is. I would not use this as a learning resource.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I took this article because I learned PHP OOP before.